# How to display Full Screen button on Windows 10 app title bar?

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

Many Universal Apps in Windows 10 display a "full screen" button in the title bar. For example:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/v012cSt.png]

How can I make this button appear in my app?

I'm programming w/ Visual Studio 2015, C#, XAML, Windows 10 SDK, etc.

Comment: Also, I think this *full screen mode toggle* was available in Windows 8.1, but they took it out in 10. My answer to that question will help you add a custom one to the title bar.

Comment: it only shows up by default for old 8.1 apps.